# Macro to auto box (primitives) if it's not NSObject

Tags: objective-c, macros, c-preprocessor

I have this macro that detects if a variable is an object:

```
#define IS_OBJECT(x) ( strchr("@#", @encode(typeof(x))[0]) != NULL )
#define AUTO_BOX(x) IS_OBJECT(x) ? x : @(x)
```

I wanted to simplify my workflow by auto box any primitives so that I can quickly do something like this:

```
BOOL v1 = YES;
id v2 = [[NSObject alloc] init];
NSLog(@"%@ %@", AUTO_BOX(v1), AUTO_BOX(v2));
//the @"%@ %@" format is non-changeable, I can't change them to @"%d %@" or @"%x %@"
```

This of course will throw error for v2 since it's an object:

```
 error: illegal type 'id' used in a boxed expression
```

What could I do to fix this?

Comment: Very interesting question. You can dig into implementation with `_Generic` usage instead of if-else-operatior

Comment: I'm guessing you meant something like this: `#define AUTO_BOX(x)  _Generic( (x), id: x, default: @(x))`. Unfortunately compiler still thrown the same error.

Comment: Yep - this is interesting, but not easily possible. I looked at this a bit, there are SO that discuss how to know if pointer points to object or if pointer points to heap or stack (angles I tried) and basic conclusion is not possible or very hacky. Compiler is aware of this (e.g. when you printf it knows if modifiers are correct) but it seems neither in compile nor runtime this is easy to figure out this side of the fence.

Answer (score 0):

```
CF_INLINE id auto_box_id_helper(const char *type, __strong id* val) {
    return *val;
}

CF_INLINE id auto_box_default_helper(const char *type, void *ptr) {
    return [NSValue valueWithBytes:ptr objCType:type];
}

#define AUTO_BOX(x) _Generic(\
        (x),\
        id: auto_box_id_helper,\
        default: auto_box_default_helper\
    )(\
        @encode(typeof((x))),\
        (typeof((x))[1]){(x)}\
    )
```

`(typeof((x))[1]){(x)}` is used instead of `&(x)`, because you can't get pointer for example from `&5`. Also you will need expand this macro with `NSNumber` parameters, if you want get `NSNumber` instead of `NSValue` for numbers.

Comment: I get `cannot initialize a parameter of type '__strong id *' with an rvalue of type 'typeof ((arg1))[1]' (aka 'id')` when tested with a variable named `arg1` of type `id`. Any idea?

Comment: @GregorIsack I have no idea, it's fine on my side. It's odd that `aka 'id'`, if it should be `aka 'id[1]'`